# Как спарсить текст поста из Instagram? [Решено]

Tags: python, парсер, api, instagram, instagram-api

**Задача:** пользователь вставляет ссылку на пост в Instagram, задача программы заключается в том, чтобы спарсить текст поста оттуда. При этом нельзя использовать способы, где нужен свой аккаунт инстраграмма / нужно войти в него, чтобы пользоваться API. То-есть, нужна библиотека или способ, метод которого бы позволял достать текст из поста по ссылке на него.

**Проблема:** пробовал разные способы, ничего не получается. Могу только получить данные по N-количеству постов пользователя, указывая его ID (который достать тоже нельзя просто так). Помогите, пожалуйста.

PS. Метод `media_info` (который в теории может дать текст поста) библиотеки instagram-private-api выдает такую ошибку `HTTPError "Method Not Allowed" while opening https://www.instagram.com/query/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена! Метод "media_info2" прекрасно работает (в отличии от media_info).